# Python for loop runs several times (not supposed to) when calling multiprosessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

My loop is crazy. When, with code under, the for loop runs two times, but the process starts only once (for each).

```
for x in range(1, 100):
    try:
        temp_kamera = 'port_kamera' + str(x)
        temp_kamera_attr = getattr(innstillinger, temp_kamera)
        print(x)
        print(temp_kamera)
        print(temp_kamera_attr)
    except:
        continue

    try:
        if isinstance(temp_kamera_attr, str):

            temp_retning = 'kjoreretning_kamera' + str(x)
            print(temp_retning)
            temp_retning = getattr(innstillinger, temp_retning)
            print(temp_retning)
            temp_prosess = 'p' + str(x)
            print(temp_prosess)
            temp_beskrivelse = 'Last inn data, fra kamera' + str(x)
            print(temp_beskrivelse)

            temp_prosess = Process(target=lastinndata, args=(queue, int(temp_kamera_attr), temp_retning),
                                   daemon=False, name=temp_beskrivelse)
            print(temp_prosess)

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                temp_prosess.start()
    except:
        continue
```

When I add these processes my previous for loop runs 4 times,process still starts only once (for each).

```
p101 = Process(target=enkeltoppslag, args=(queue,),
               daemon=False, name='Enkeltoppslag og lagring til database.')
p102 = Process(target=sletting, args=(), daemon=False,
               name='Sletting av reg. nr for eldre oppføringer.')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p101.start()
    p102.start()

    p101.join()
    p102.join()
```

Any explanation or help to what I am doing wrong? I haven't added a join for the loop processes, but they are infinite loops listening for TCP on ports.

Tried to start multiprosessor processes with for loop. When processes are beeing called the loop runs more than once. If I remove the processes the loop runs only once like it should. I also tried with a while loop, with a incrementing x, same thing happens.

Comment: `try: ... except: continue` is a really bad practice, as anything in your code can be failing and your code wouldn't complain about it. I'd remove it first and see if there's any issue on the loop itself.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. Looks like you have a class *innstillinger* that **may** contain attributes 'port_kamera1' to 'port_kamera99' and you want to start a sub-process for each of those. Is that correct?

Comment: Pingu - I have a file import innstillinger that may contain attributes port_kamera1 to 99.

Comment: Gustavo Kawamoto - I know what the error message is. It will give error for every camera that is not pressent in the file innstillinger. continue is just so I don't have to see error message, but I'will try to print the error code in the except.

Comment: Error is: module 'innstillinger' has no attribute 'port_kamera2' to 99  since I only have one camera now. This runs 4 times so a lot of error printing. But the program works. I just don't know why this loop runs four times.

Comment: @MA You only show one loop here. If it runs 4 times then it's because of code that you haven't shown. Can you say more about "file import innstillinger". It doesn't really make sense. *getattribute()* doesn't work (directly) on files

Comment: file import innstillinger is just a python setup file. getattribute() is just to get the value of the variable in that file. The loop runs four times, but the process only starts once. (each camera like it should) Maybe because I have four processes with the same name because of all the loop runs.   It run four times because of Process whitch is part of mulitprocessing, if I removes the processes then the loop only runs once. The process runs three different functions, maybe there is something in them, program has run for months without problem before I added this loop.